# $F(x):=\int_{[a,x)} f(t) \lambda(dt)$ is absolutely continuous for all $f \in L^1(\lambda)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am looking at the solution to the following exercise from Rene Schilling's Measures, Integrals and Martingales. However, below in the second inequality for $|F(y_n)-F(x_n)|$, I cannot figure out why $\int_{[x_n,y_n)\cap \{|f|>R\}}|f(t)|\lambda(dt) \le \lambda(\{|f|>R\}\cap [x_n,y_n))$. Here we don't have $|f|\le 1$, so I don't think this actually works. But the rest of the proof relies on this inequality. How can I resolve this problem?

$F(x):=\int_{[a,x)} f(t) \lambda(dt)$ is absolutely continuous for all $f \in L^1(\lambda)$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $f\in L^{1}(\lambda)$ implies that $\displaystyle\int|f|d\lambda-\int_{|f|\leq R}|f|d\lambda\rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$, this is just Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Therefore, we have $\displaystyle\int_{|f|>R}|f|d\lambda\rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$. Pick an $R>0$ large enough that $\displaystyle\int_{[x_{n},y_{n})\cap\{|f|>R\}}|f|d\lambda\leq\int_{|f|>R}|f|d\lambda$ small enough.

Comment: This solves the problem but there isn't a way to get this specific estimate $\int_{[x_n,y_n)\cap \{|f|>R\}}|f(t)|\lambda(dt) \le \lambda(\{|f|>R\}\cap [x_n,y_n))$? The author uses it in another problem so I was wondering if this really holds.

Comment: Probability measure in question?

Comment: Just the same Lebesgue measure restricted on $(x_j,y_j)$.So $\int_{(x_j,y_j)} f(t) \lambda(dt) \le R\int_{(x_j,y_j)} \lambda(dt) + \lambda(\{f \ge R\} \cap (x_j,y_j))$.

Comment: I fail to see why that goes through.